# How to combine Share object query?

Tags: apex, sharerecord

Again raising the question from the link. Case is Private and Payment is also Private. Payment has lookup relationship with the Case.

I have developed code which create share object for Case and Payment object.

How to combine below two query ? Is that possible to combine ?

```
SELECT CaseAccessLevel,CaseId,Id,IsDeleted,LastModifiedById,LastModifiedDate,RowCause,UserOrGroupId FROM CaseShare where CaseId = 'YYYY'

SELECT AccessLevel,Id,IsDeleted,LastModifiedById,LastModifiedDate,ParentId,RowCause,UserOrGroupId FROM Payment__Share where ParentId = 'XXXX'
```

Answer (score 0):

Share Objects do not store relationship between Case and Payment objects. So you need to use two separate queries.